# SSH authentication fails when trying to access Bitbucket from Jenkins

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, git, public-key, jenkins

I'm trying to currently set up a Jenkins CI-server in Azure that pulls the project from Bitbucket and runs the tests. CI-server is running Ubuntu 14.10.

I got the server running, and I generated ssh-keys with ssh-keygen (no passphrase), and added the public key in Bitbucket under the deployment keys. If I type ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org as the user jenkins while in SSH session through console I get:

```
ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org
authenticated via a deploy key
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

I can also git clone the project from Bitbucket, as the SSH key works in the command line. However, when I go to add a new build through the Jenkins control panel (Configure). I'm adding the GIT credentials like this:

```
Repository URL: git@bitbucket.org:name/project_name.git
Credentials: the private key in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Error I'm getting

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:name/project_name.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

When trying to build I get the same error as above. Any clue what I might be doing wrong here? To my knowledge Jenkins uses user "jenkins", unless stated otherwise, and that's the user I'm using in command line when getting "authenticated via a deploy key".

Thanks for all the answers :)